# Is there any way to configure windows to not change the focus?

Tags: windows, configuration

I'm tired of being in the middle of typing something, having a pop-up with a question appear, and hitting enter before reading it... (it also happens with some windows that are not pop-ups)

Do you know if there's some setting I could touch for this not to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suppose to be a [registry change](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/regentry/55200.mspx?mfr=true)  that helps with this type of situations (mentioned in [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001011.html) Coding Horror post about the subject of "focus stealing"). I try it, it doesn't work with *all* popups but helps with some of them, causing the offending application to flash in the taskbar instead of gain focus.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. This has been a plague of Windows versions for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Windows XP tries to avoid that. Of course some programs found a way to [circumvented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505/sending-a-mouse-click-to-a-button-in-the-taskbar-using-c) that. Microsoft Powertoy TweakUI has a way to turn the option on again in case it was turned off. You could also edit the registry yourself using the [following information](http://xphelpandsupport.mvps.org/how_do_i_prevent_applications_fr.htm).