# To avoid the Windows form to disappear under the task bar when opened as IE page

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()` for open new IE page ,for mainley used height and width set for IE page But my application open as new IE page goes under the tool bar. After i will click it will open which I tried many ways.

Please give any idea to open IE with height and width.

below my code:

```
var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
object URL = "http://www.northwind.com";

IE.ToolBar = 0;
IE.StatusBar = false;
IE.MenuBar = false;
IE.Width = 540;
IE.Height = 640;
IE.Visible = true;

IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
```

Comment: By "toolbar" do you mean "taskbar" or _toolbar_ than already exists in your app

Comment: dispaly in taskbar

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the problem so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: my problem is IE not shown as screen.it displayed in task bar and blinking.after i will click blinking it will shown in screen.

Comment: Events like [WindowActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768314(v=vs.85).aspx), [WindowMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768316(v=vs.85).aspx),
[WindowResize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768318(v=vs.85).aspx) hasn't been implemented for [InternetExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx). So you would have to do some kind of combo of SendKeys and WindowHooks i guess

Comment: we need to implements these events necessary for IE

Comment: How to implement ?can you explain clearly.i am using IE 11

Comment: You don't have to implement these events. Instead have a look at similar topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505/sending-a-mouse-click-to-a-button-in-the-taskbar-using-c-sharp)